Get XGBoost prediction based on individual trees
It might be duplicated from How to get each individual tree's prediction in xgboost? but the solution no longer works (possibly to changes on XGBoost library). My idea is to dump the model in a raw format model.get_booster().get_dump() and implement it in a different platform (prediction only). However, I'm first trying to implement it in python. Running the following code, making predictions using all the individual booster and combining them, does not return the same result as the model.predict() function.
Is there any way I can match the model.predict() with the combination of the boosters? What am I missing?
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn import datasets
from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid, logit as inverse_sigmoid

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, (iris.target == 1).astype(int)

# Fit a model
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(
    n_estimators=10,
    max_depth=10,
    use_label_encoder=False,
    objective='binary:logistic'
)
model.fit(X, y)
booster_ = model.get_booster()

# Extract indivudual predictions
individual_preds = []
for tree_ in booster_:
    individual_preds.append(
        tree_.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X))
    )
individual_preds = np.vstack(individual_preds)

# Aggregated individual predictions to final predictions
indivudual_logits = inverse_sigmoid(individual_preds)
final_logits = indivudual_logits.sum(axis=0)
final_preds = sigmoid(final_logits)

# Verify correctness
xgb_preds = booster_.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X))
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(final_preds, xgb_preds)


AssertionError: Arrays are not almost equal to 7 decimals
Mismatched elements: 150 / 150 (100%)
Max absolute difference: 0.90511334
Max relative difference: 0.99744916
x: array([7.4847587e-05, 7.4847587e-05, 7.4847587e-05, 7.4847587e-05,
7.4847587e-05, 7.4847587e-05, 7.4847587e-05, 7.4847587e-05,
7.4847587e-05, 7.4847587e-05, 7.4847587e-05, 7.4847587e-05,...
y: array([0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127,
0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127,
0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127, 0.0293127,...


The two most obvious (to me) candidates are learning rate and base score, but adding (each subset of) these to your example doesn't reconcile the differences for me.  Hmm.

The LR shouldn't matter, right? I mean, for predictions.
About the base score, I believe the delta would be always the same if it were the case.

I'm pretty sure it is related to the base_score but haven't figured it out yet.

The reason is because it is a boosting mechanism. Note the code in the for loop below, we need to update the base_margin each time. And the final result is NOT simply sum of all trees, but the results from the last tree.
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn import datasets
from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid,logit

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, (iris.target == 1).astype(int)

# Set basic model parameters
base_score = 0.5
n_rounds = 10
# Fit a model
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(
    n_estimators=n_rounds,
    base_score=0.5,
    max_depth=10,
    use_label_encoder=False,
    objective='binary:logistic'
)
model.fit(X, y)
booster_ = model.get_booster()

# Extract indivudual predictions
scores = np.full((X.shape[0],), logit(base_score))

individual_logits = []
for tree_ in booster_:

    X_margin = xgb.DMatrix(X, base_margin=scores)
    # get raw leaf value for accumulation
    scores = tree_.predict(
        X_margin, output_margin=True
    )

    individual_logits.append(
        scores
    )
individual_logits = np.vstack(individual_logits)

individual_preds = sigmoid(individual_logits)
final_preds = individual_preds[n_rounds-1,]
# Verify correctness
xgb_preds = booster_.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X))

np.testing.assert_almost_equal(final_preds, xgb_preds)


This is very helpful in directing a search, but I don't think it's entirely correct yet.  I can recover equality by removing the base_margin=scores and summing the logits instead of just taking the last (as I'd expect: the base score is just the sum of the predictions so far).  The addition of output_margin=True in the prediction seems to work better than trying to apply logit to the predicted probability.  I still can't entirely reconcile the issue though, with different base_score set on the classifier...

You are right when setting base_score=0.5, and "removing the base_margin=scores and summing the logits". I'm a little confused too. However, when base_score is set at other values, the code above could still pass the assertion test, and the summing logit method did not pass in my tests.

Never mind, after all, I did not explain well. I just tried and found it work that way. To my understanding, in boosting, we are using weighted sum of all weak learners, and for the last learner, it should work on the most difficult samples. However, in the current result, we just use the last weak learner, and it became the final result..

It seems like the issue might be related to how you're aggregating the predictions from individual trees. Instead of summing up the logits directly, you should consider averaging them. Since you're dealing with binary classification, averaging the logits makes more sense. The below code might help you:
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn import datasets
from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid, logit as inverse_sigmoid

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, (iris.target == 1).astype(int)

# Fit a model
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(
    n_estimators=10,
    max_depth=10,
    use_label_encoder=False,
    objective='binary:logistic'
)
model.fit(X, y)
booster_ = model.get_booster()

# Extract individual predictions
individual_preds = []
for tree_ in booster_:
    individual_preds.append(
        tree_.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X))
    )
individual_preds = np.vstack(individual_preds)

# Aggregated individual predictions to final predictions
individual_logits = inverse_sigmoid(individual_preds)
final_logits = np.mean(individual_logits, axis=0)  # Use mean instead of sum
final_preds = sigmoid(final_logits)

# Verify correctness
xgb_preds = booster_.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X))
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(final_preds, xgb_preds)

By taking the mean of the logits, you'll ensure that the predictions are more aligned with the model's predict function.

This shouldn't work.  Gradient boosting is additive: the targets of one tree are the (pseudo-)residuals of the previous ensemble.  Does this snippet actually work?

It doesn't work.
